# difference of two sets (lists) in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, data-structures

```
stb_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]
passive_boxes_list = []
active_boxes_list = set(stb_list) - set(passive_boxes_list)
print active_boxes_list
```

I have got two lists. The number is going to be added into the `passive_boxes_list` dynamically (1-16).

How I can subtract `stb_list` from `passive_box_list`.

For example: if `passive_boxes_list = [1 , 2 , 3]` then `active_box_list` should be:

```
active_boxes_list = [4, 5,6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13,14,15,16]
```

Comment: Are you after some kind of view which updates each time passive_boxes_list dynamically updates?

Comment: Your code already works, doesn't it? (Although you could potentially convert `active_boxes_list` to a `list` from a `set`.) Can you be more specific about what behaviour you want? If you want something that really updates dynamically, you're going to have to build a function or a class. (Also, I think the name operation is just "difference", not "distraction", in English)

Comment: One possibility that is about as terse as any other that doesn't involve a non-pythonic amount of reliance on globals or other magic: `active_boxes_list -= set(passive_boxes_list)`

Comment: perhaps this is better as a class to encapsulate the moving of number between estates and so you can easily update both when a new active or passive is added

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
bleh=[1,2,3,10]
for x in bleh:
    if x in list:
        del list[list.index(x)]
print list
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use the [List Comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) feature.
 So you should have something like `active_boxes_list = [x for x in stb_list if x not in passive_list]`

Hope this help !

Comment: The OP's `set` commands already do this part of the job (more elegantly)!